# Table/CSS/Div - 2 rows 2 cols (2nd col spans rows)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a table structure with the following format:

```
-----------------------
| Title     | Sidebar |  Total table height a minimum of 500px 
|-----------|         |  Title takes as little space as possible
| Main Text |         |  Main & Sidebar both fill to minimum height.
|           |         |
-----------------------
```

I have the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hjbh7z4/6/) which works in Chrome/Safari, but IE11 splits the Title and Main to have equal widths. Is this possible in IE? do I need to employ some div structures to fill it out properly.

html code

```
    <div style="background-color: #00f;width:356px; min-height:500px;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
        <tbody>
            <tr style="height:0%;">
                <td class="title">
                    <div style="background-color: #f0f">Title! - use as little space as possible</div>
                </td>
                <td rowspan=2 class="sidebar">Sidebar content! / should extend to min height and past if needed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:100%">
                <td class="main"><div class=main style="height:100%;">Main Content! / should fill to match red sidebar b</div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

css code

```
table {
  height:500px; /* and not height=500px; */
  width:350px;
  }

.title {
  height:0;
}
td.title {
    vertical-align: text-top;
    background-color:#333;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 10px;
    border-spacing: 15px;
}
td.main {
    vertical-align: text-top;
    background-color:#888;
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 100%;
}
td.sidebar {
    vertical-align:top;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #f00;
    width: 35%;
}
```

I believe I could do this using css tables, but I'm currently stuck trying to fix a current site without totally reworking all the pages stored in the mysql database.

Comment: Are you displaying tabular data?  i.e. statistics, values, or something like you'd find in a spreadsheet?  If not, you should be using a CSS layout and not <table>

Comment: It's currently a table w/ the Main Title, A sidebar w/ links to other info about the page, a the main body. Similar to the structure of this page. I realize CSS is the best long term solution, but I'm not ready to tell the new boss I need to rewrite 100s of pages stored in the mysql database. (where these 3 content areas were not separate fields, but 1 html chunk of code).

Comment: added a screen of the render of my code you just copied/paste that works in my IE11  :)

Comment: If the answer below is correct and exactly what you need, please do mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

you only need to set:

```
table {
height:500px; /* and not height=500px; */
}
.title {
height:1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4hjbh7z4/8/
[image: IE11 screen shot]

```css
div {
  width: 356px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;/* fix widths */
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #00f;
}
td.title {
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #f0f;
  padding: 15px;/*there was border-spacing here ? */
}
td.main {
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #888;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td.sidebar {
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="title">Title! - use as little space as possible</td>
        <td rowspan=2 class="sidebar">Sidebar content! / should extend to min height and past if needed</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="main">Main Content! / should fill to match red sidebar b</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought I'd fixed that = before I submitted the question. It still does not make a difference in IE11.

Comment: @GSnclr well it did right away in mine. what about a refresh of your page or the fiddle linked or even the snippet here ?

Comment: It looks great in IE11, but column 1 is now split in Chrome/Safari. Looks like I may need a 2 browser solution.

Comment: That's it. I had that setting as 10px once, but must I have had another setting wrong. It's a good week now.